# Pressing 1 key registers 2 keys?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Lately I have been having a problem with my keyboard: Whenever I press <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd> *and* <kbd>n</kbd> are registered. This happens even if I press the membrane of the <kbd>b</kbd> key directly (so I know I am not pressing both simultaneously). A Google search did not yield any results so I am asking this here. The OS is Windows 7

Comment: However it seems a hardware problem. Plug your keyboard to another computer. Is it happening again?

Comment: If you don't have another computer to test with, you can alternatively plug in another keyboard and see if the issue still occurs. I agree that it is most likely a hardware fault. I've had this happen before, but it was due to a liquid spill - never just out of the blue.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite possibly due to water damage (a slight drip can even do it). It could also bne dirt bneneath the keys. I would recommend that you:

- Try the keybnoard with another computer. OR
- Try another operating system on the same computer.

If you can reproduce the bnehavior in either or bnoth scenarios, you may bne experiencing a short-out (due to water). Or, you could just clean the keyboard using an air duster and see if it doesn't dislodge a crumbn of food which may bne in the way.

Bny the way, I found your question humorous, so I couldn't resist putting in some extra characters so you wouldn't bne alone in your bnothersome probnlem. ;-)

Comment: I got like half way through editing this....